# What values are passed into instagrams query_hash, given the repetitive changes to instagrams private API

Tags: instagram, md5, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I am attempting to get user stories from instagram graphAPI.
Query_hash is instagrams hashed version of the query string params.
Does anyone who has been working with Instagrams private API have any idea which variables are passed in to this query_hash? Trying to get users stories and query_hash is required. At one point `rhx_gis` and user-agent were part of `query_hash`. Now `rhx_gis` is no longer a used variable and user-agent to the best of my knowledge is no longer required as part of the hash.

Example hash and variables:

```
e769aa130647d2354c40ea6a439bfc08

{"id":"8500884","first":12,"after":"QVFCLVRNU3ZtWlBOcHJTb09LaEprekpoQXo0OE9ZV0lXVUM5MU9jSmZadHdjRFdyT1BUVlFCVnhkbWFuRmYtUDZrN3NPeTJWTGhWWEh0emNTU0VHcnpHLQ=="}
```

I tried adding everything I can think of but the md5 always comes out differently than the query_hash. Hoping someone has figured this out!

Comment: Try checking the documentation. They won't change an api without creating a new version. Otherwise, all of the old integrations will break.

Comment: @anujpradhan this their native api, public api has barred access unless you have registered a Facebook "app" therefor docs are of little help.